# Visio shapes stencils Metro style

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes, modern-ui

I can not find Visio Stencil Metro style for simple services: DNS, DHCP, RRAS, and so on.

Found Visio stencil at Metro:

[New Office Visio Stencil](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35772)

[Office Visio Stencil for Exchange 2013.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36448)

If possible, give link to Visio Stencil style Metro, sample:

[image: Visio Stencil Metro style]

Agree on a set of pictures in the style of metro.

Thank you so much!

Comment: They might not exit if your downloaded the templates and what your looking for didn't exit then it wasn't in the template set you inatalled